# nmap output with awk to table

Tags: awk, nmap

I'm trying to get `nmap` output as a table or at least straight columns. I'm  using this command:

```
$ sudo nmap -sn 192.168.103.0/24 \
    | awk '/Nmap scan report for/{printf $5;}/MAC Address:/{print ","substr($0, index($0,$3)) }' \
    | sort -t . -k 4,4n
```

However, I want it to show me:

```
ip    mac address     hostname
```

without `()` around the ip or hostname, but I can't manage to do it.

Comment: You seem to have two profiles [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/411908/joni-jino) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/411728/joni-jino); you may want to merge them.

Comment: Check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76980293/1147688).

Answer (score 1):

If you have the wonderful `xmlstarlet` you can parse the XML output from `nmap` and generate almost any table you want

```
nmap -sn -oX - 192.168.1.0/24 |
    xmlstarlet sel -t \
            -m '/nmaprun/host[status/@state="up"]' \
            -v 'address[@addrtype="ipv4"]/@addr' -o $'\t' \
            -v 'address[@addrtype="mac"]/@addr' -o $'\t' \
            -v 'hostnames/hostname[1]/@name' -n
```

Example XML output looks like this

```
<nmaprun scanner="nmap" args="nmap -sn -oX - 192.168.1.0/24" start="1589146436" startstr="Sun May 10 21:33:56 2020" version="7.70" xmloutputversion="1.04">
  <verbose level="0"/>
  <debugging level="0"/>
  <host>
    <status state="up" reason="arp-response" reason_ttl="0"/>
    <address addr="192.168.130.6" addrtype="ipv4"/>
    <address addr="01:55:1E:C3:68:A3" addrtype="mac" vendor="SomeManufacturer"/>
    <hostnames>
      <hostname name="host6.roaima.co.uk" type="PTR"/>
    </hostnames>
    <times srtt="119229" rttvar="119229" to="596145"/>
  </host>
  <host>...</host>
  <host>...</host>
  <runstats>
    <finished time="1589146444" timestr="Sun May 10 21:34:04 2020" elapsed="8.09" summary="Nmap done at Sun May 10 21:34:04 2020; 256 IP addresses (4 hosts up) scanned in 8.09 seconds" exit="success"/>
    <hosts up="4" down="252" total="256"/>
  </runstats>
</nmaprun>
```

Example processed output, showing just four devices responding to the the `nmap` ping request

```
192.168.1.6     01:55:1E:C3:68:A3       host6.roaima.co.uk
192.168.1.8     92:66:9B:20:F1:17
192.168.1.15    53:77:5E:EA:FD:03       client15.roaima.co.uk
192.168.1.31    C4:88:FB:6C:64:AE
```

The `xmlstarlet` tool uses XPath to pick out XML elements and attributes, either matching them (`-m`) or extracting the value (`-v`).

Comment: In order to get the MAC addresses, one has to run the nmap command with sudo.
Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14165492/2278742

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `awk`, this script may help.

```
nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24 |
    awk '
        function out() { if (state=="up") { printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n",ip,mac,name; ip=""; mac=""; name=""; state="" } }

        /Nmap scan report/ { out(); name=$5; ip = substr($6,2,length($6)-2); if (ip=="") { ip=name; name="" } }
        /Host is/ { state=$3 }
        /MAC Address/ { mac=$3 }

        END { out() }
    '
```

It can be rolled into a single line if you want.

Example output, showing just four devices responding to the the `nmap` ping request

```
192.168.1.6     01:55:1E:C3:68:A3       host6.roaima.co.uk
192.168.1.8     92:66:9B:20:F1:17
192.168.1.15    53:77:5E:EA:FD:03       client15.roaima.co.uk
192.168.1.31    C4:88:FB:6C:64:AE
```